# User Friendly .NET CMS

Tags: asp.net, cms

I am looking for a recommendation for a somewhat powerful but more importantly user friendly CMS for .NET.

The ones I have found seem decent at best.

*If you say DotNetNuke I will be tempted to reach through this screen and slap you...*

Edit: I have made it community wiki. Please add 1 CMS per answer so the best may rise to the top.

Comment: What ones have you found and what didn't you like about them?

Comment: The one most people seem to recommend was n2 and I really didn't like how confusing it was. The most promising one I have found is Orchard but its still to buggy for production use.

Comment: I think this is a fantastic question. I have never found one that I deem as user friendly. It is subjective sure.. but this will be a great resource if people contribute to it. It should probably be a Community Wiki.

Comment: So what happens if I randomly vote some up and some down to mess with the poll like nature of the question?

Comment: @George The invisible hand of the crowd will correct it. None of us is as dumb as all of us!

Comment: @corymathews: What did you find that was confusing about it?

Comment: HAhAHAA!!! :)) +1 for slapping dnn suggestions ;)

Comment: Wow! How has no one recommended SharePoint? Or is that telling in itself?

Comment: SharePoint and "user-friendly" in the same sentence? :-S

Answer (score 7):

As you mentioned, [Orchard](http://orchard.codeplex.com/) has a lot of [potential](http://live.visitmix.com/MIX10/Sessions/FT06), but it is still pretty young and not quite ready for production use. [Umbraco](http://umbraco.codeplex.com/) is another .NET CMS that has pretty good reviews.

Comment: I went to a code camp where an Umbraco dev showed off what it could do.  Awesome system, but needs full trust to run so many shared hosting accounts are out.

Comment: Umbraco is indeed awesome

Comment: You should be able to use Umbraco 4.5 in medium trust - see last comment on http://our.umbraco.org/forum/getting-started/installing-umbraco/10431-Installing-Umbraco-on-shared-hosting-or-Medium-trust

Answer (score 7):

[BlogEngine.NET](http://www.dotnetblogengine.net/) is a basic open source one that should be considered.  It is geared towards blog posts, but it has the concept of "pages" and can be themed very easily.

Answer (score 4):

I've found that [N2](http://n2cms.com) is a very good, user friendly CMS.

I've built a couple of sites on it that I've handed over to fairly non-technical people to run, and they've managed to do so very successfully - one of the users has had experiences of editing web sites in the past, and said that this was one of best ones they'd used.

The latest version makes the editing experience even nicer apparently, although I have to admit I've not had a chance to look at it myself.

I've also written a simple user guide (albeit tailored to the pages I'd produced, but could be a good starting point, let me know if you want to take a look).

Comment: Add the user guide!

Comment: @Wolfwyrd: It's a word doc, and in terms of the pages is focused on the site I built, I didn't think it appropriate to include the entire thing in here.

Comment: tried probably all .net cms, but N2 beat them all! If there's something like Wordpress of .net, then it's N2. Period. And, important feature for me, adding new content types is really easy (like product/categories pages, details, lists,...)

Answer (score 2):

I really like [Sitefinity](http://sitefinity.com/) from Telerik.  There's a community edition or a fairly inexpensive commercial edition.  It's easy to make templates for, easy for end users, and has a well documented API for building custom modules.

Comment: User-friendly is a somewhat relative term.  However, we genuinely do take this pretty seriously with Sitefinity.  Here is the experience we're trying to create - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gCnYb4MbYD8

Answer (score 1):

Creating and maintaining a site has never been easier. Graffiti CMS allows you to quickly publish and maintain dynamic content Web sites with little or no knowledge of Web programming.

http://graffiticms.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

I've been playing with the Kentico CMS recently and that's simple and easy to use. Very powerful as well if you want to extend it.

Answer (score 0):

I did a research on this not a long time ago. A user friendly CMS is a really basic demand for a CMS. What is it for, what are the things it needs to be able to do...

If usability is a must, Telerik Sitefinity is actually a good choice, and enables you to use a lot of the functionalities a Web CMS needs.

If money is not an issue... I would recommend Sitecore. Stable, endless possibilities and user friendly!

PS: 2 CMS' in one answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

[Sitecore](http://www.sitecore.net) is a powerhouse commercial CMS, but is somewhat expensive.  It has a very expansive editor UI, with all types of customization.

Answer (score 0):

I would vouch for [Umbraco.](http://umbraco.org/) It's not called the "friendly CMS" for nothing. I've built a lot of sites in it and it's very flexible and, importantly, client's tend to like it as it's intuitive and simple to use.

On top of that it's also open-source, free and has a great and active [community](http://our.umbraco.org/). It's also powerful - for instance, Microsoft use it to power the official [ASP.NET website](http://www.asp.net/) (check the footer).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at **[Composite C1](http://compositec1.codeplex.com/)** - it's Free Open Source and available on MS Web Platform Installer and WebMatrix and is imo worth checking out, especially if user friendliness is key. It's based on .NET 4. There is a bunch of UI demo videos here: http://www.youtube.com/user/compositec1#p/u

Answer (score 0):

My vote goes to the new MonoX. Apart from all standard CMS features it has a nice selection of social networking modules. Nice, powerful and free.

http://monox.mono-software.com

Answer (score 0):

[Oxite (alpha)](http://visitmix.com/labs/oxite/) is an open source, standards compliant, and extensible content management sample that can run anything from blogs to big web sites.